# here api deep linking by routeId

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

I'm generating and storing a route using the HERE api.

I would like to create a link to share the route, using the stored routeId.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing/topics/resource-get-route.html for this.

Caching or storing any location data for the purpose of building a repository of location assets or scaling one request to serve multiple end users is prohibited. You may not use any HERE Property in a manner that pre-fetches, caches, or stores data or results, except:

```
- As explicitly allowed by the caching headers (HTTP/1.1 standard) returned by HERE services; or
- To the extent you are storing or caching for no more than thirty (30) days only to the extent necessary for enabling or improving an end user's use of the HERE services
```

You can read more about Here Terms in legal.here.com/en-gb/terms/acceptable-use-policy.

Please make sure you are inline with our terms.